# How do I get the name of the current Listbox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

according to [How to address generated ListBoxes and add Items dynamically in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871346/how-to-address-generated-listboxes-and-add-items-dynamically-in-vba) I generated several ListBoxes dynamically which I assigned a OnAction Sub to. The OnAction Event shall show me the amount of selected Items of the *current* ListBox.

For better understanding:

e.g. I generated 5 Listboxes (ListBox1, ListBox2, ...) on my Worksheet "FS".

When I click 1 item on ListBox1, MsgBox shows up with "1".

If I click an additional item on ListBox1, MsgBox shows "2".

But If i click another Item of ListBox3, MsgBox shall show "1".

```
    'ListBoxName as a variable for current ListBox and probably the most problematic line
    ListBoxName = ActiveControl.Name

    selectedItems = 0

    Set lb = FS.ListBoxes(ListBoxName)

    'The following counts the selected items in target ListBox
    For i = 1 To lb.ListCount Step 1
        If lb.Selected(i) Then
            selectedItems = selectedItems + 1
        End If
    Next i

    'This part puts up the Message Box with the number of selected items in target ListBox
    If selectedItems > 0 Then
        MsgBox selectedItems
    End If
```

Additional information: I left out the declarations of the variables for better overview. I am *not* using ActiveX and I am *not* using a UserForm. Getting the current name of the Listbox will help me with further programming and tasks I want to do. In my mind it looked so easy to find the name of the ListBox on which I did my latest click...

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**:
The code is placed in a module "Module1" in Sub Module1. In another Module "generation", where I generate the ListBoxes, the Module1 is started with `lb.OnAction = "Module1.Module1"`.

**EDIT2**
Changed "OnClick" to "OnAction"

Comment: Where is this code placed?

Comment: @SJR I edited my post regarding your input

Comment: So these are Forms controls on the sheet and your code is a normal sub in a standard module? I'm not clear how your code is run. I don't think `ActiveControl` is right. Forms listboxes don't have a Click event.

Comment: Yes. The Form Controls are generated and their Properties assigned in Module "Generation". You are absolutely right, there is no "OnClick" Event but it seems, that there is a "OnAction" Event. I know that, because i programmed it with a "OnAction" Event and it worked. But only if i specify the ListBox.

Comment: Then the answer below should work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `ActiveControl` for Form listboxes. To get the name of the Form listbox which called the ONCLICK event, use [Application.Caller property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller)

In the `ONCLICK` event of the forms listbox, put this.

```
Sub ONCLICK()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Shapes(Application.Caller)

    '~~> This will give you the value of what is selected in that listbox
    MsgBox shp.ControlFormat.List(shp.ControlFormat.Value)
End Sub
```

**Note**: If the above code is not in the respective sheet code area then you will have to chnage `Shapes(Application.Caller)` to `Activesheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)` as Yasser mentioned below.

Comment: Great. I think this part `Shapes(Application.Caller)` should be preceded with `ActiveSheet` for example